# Banned from Flagging - How to avoid?

Tags: discussion, flag-ban

I get a ban from flagging because to many flags on the last 7 days are declined. The declined posts are the following (all flagged with `not an answer`):

- [What does the error "Bad gateway" mean on Kibana Dashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897920/what-does-the-error-bad-gateway-mean-on-kibana-dashboard/37249566#37249566)
  Should be a comment and is not a very good answer.
- [Find the string length of a Lua number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393869/find-the-string-length-of-a-lua-number/37237343#37237343)
  This is a question for clarification and should not be an answer.
- [BOLT won't render the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110375/bolt-wont-render-the-html/37110480#37110480)
  OK this could be an answer, but for me a low quality answer.

In my opinion the flags should not be declined. How can I avoid to get banned? Should I stop flagging?

Comment: Two of them have been controvertial, flag-wise: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37237343/timeline and http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37249566/timeline

Comment: Perhaps if you explained why you think those answers are not answers. Some of them have rhetorical questions, has that concept confused you?

Comment: 1 isn't great but I think 2 is an answer in the form of a rhetorical question and I don't see why 3 is low quality it could equally have been written as "you likely did X, if so fix it by doing Y".